# find inverse (x, y pos) point in circle

Tags: math, geometry, coordinates

I have a fixed point (x1, y1) and a moving/rotating point (x2, y2), how do I find the tangent inverse point (x3, y3)

My circle radius is 40.

[image: circle]

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: There's no "tangent" here and not really an "inverse" either. I would call the point you're looking for simply the point "opposite" from the given point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `p1` and `p2` are 2-vectors, the following will do it.

```
v12 = normalize(p2 - p1) // the unit vector from p1 to p2
p3 = p1 - 40 * v12       // 40 away from p1 in the direction opposite p2
```

The value of `normalize(u)` is simply `u / sqrt(u.x * u.x + u.y * u.y)`.

Comment: Thereby showing that no trigonometry is required for this question.

Answer (score 0):

achieved it this way, modified to be rotated to any angle

http://jsfiddle.net/christianpugliese/g2Lk9k12/1/

```
var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;
var radianAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
var diameter = -80;

p3x = x1 + diameter * Math.cos(radianAngle);
p3y = y1 + diameters * Math.sin(radianAngle);
```